# Converse to Proposition 2.23 in Darmon, Diamond, Taylor's FLT Notes

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, galois-representations

Can someone either prove or link me to a reference for Remark 2.24 (page 64) [here](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf)? I am told that SGA7 covers this for general abelian varieties. I am wondering if a) anyone can pinpoint where in SGA7 this is covered, and b) if there is a less heavy reference that perhaps only covers this for elliptic curves. All needed definitions are on page 62 in the same document.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is contained in Takeshi Saito's books on FLT?

Comment: Yes! Page 103 of book 1, for future readers.